# Calling ParseUser.save deletes Session

Tags: android, session, parse-platform

I use the parse.com backend for Android.

I want to sign up a new user and after that set some data field on the user object. It is important for me to set the data field after the sign up, because later I want to enable automatic ACL setting using beforeSave triggers (currently no triggers are activated!).

What happens is the following: The sign up completes successfully and after that I set the data field and call `currentUser.save`. Sometimes the `SaveCallback` is not called at all (neither with an error, nor successfully). However, most of the times it is called but the Session for the user is deleted. I can easily check that in the Data Browser. Also, I get invalid session exceptions if I try to do anything after that.

Here's the code:

```
final User user = getData();
user.setEmail(emailStr);
user.setUsername(emailStr);
user.setPassword(password);

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // this will be more complex data in the future
            User.getCurrentUser().put("testInt", 5);
            User.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // Hooray! But wait.. Oh no, the session is gone
                    } else {
                        // Oh no, something even worse happened
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            // signup failed
        }
    }
});
```

After over one day of try&error I'm starting to believe that this is actually a bug in the Parse framework. The [guide](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users) explicitly states:

> New ParseUsers should always be created using the signUpInBackground (or signUp) method. Subsequent updates to a user can be done by calling save.

Does anyone have similar behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call save after signup, put your data before and signup will save them. Also you have to log the user in after sign up. On success call parseuser.logininbackground; this should create a logged in session.
Prior to login parse keeps an anonymous session after login a user session is created.

Comment: 1. As I said I really want to avoid saving the data with the signup because I want to use the triggers which only work if a user is signed in.

2. Are you sure that I have to call login after signup? Because the [doc](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#signUp%28%29) states:
"This will create a new ParseUser on the server, and also persist the session on disk so that you can access the user using `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`".
Also, if I remove the call to `save` and just signup a user session object is created as expected.